# Variable substitution for column position in a read_csv data frame based on raw_input

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to simplify my code...What I am trying to do is to have a user input a number. Based on the number they select, it will print out the data from the corresponding column in a csv. Here is my code:

### Reads the csv and filters only necessary columns:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/test_1.csv', usecols=[0,1], header = 0)
```

### Gets input from the user and assigns a variable:

```
n = raw_input("Please enter first choice: ")
```

### Does checks for blank entries, matches the raw_input entry, and prints out the results for the column:

```
if n != '' and n == '0':
    print df1.ix[:, 0]
elif n != '' and n == '1':
   print df1.ix[:, 1]
else:
   print "stop"
```

All this works. However, I don't feel it is optimal or efficient coding.

I would have to list all possible combinations for column numbers. If I have multiple user input questions, it becomes unwieldy.

I would like to dynamically be able to take the user input, assign a variable, and place that variable into a single line which will print out a column's information.

### In my mind (as abstract):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/test_1.csv', usecols=[0,1], header = 0)
number=raw_input("Please enter first choice: ")
print df1.ix[:, number]
```

I am new to Python and could definitely use assistance. Thanks in advance!!

Tiberius

Comment: so why can't you cast `number` to an actual `number` by casting to `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
from __future__ import print_function

df1 = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/test_1.csv', usecols=[0,1], header = 0)


while True:
    try:
        number = int(raw_input("Please enter first choice: "))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid integer.')
        continue
    try:
        print(df1.ix[:, number])
    except IndexError:
        print('Please enter an index between 0 and {}'.format(len(df) - 1))
        continue
    break
```

Comment: After taking your answer and dissecting my query, I found out exactly what I had done wrong. I did not specify that they type of raw_input needed to be an int. Line 5 of your solution did that with: int(raw_input("Please enter first choice: ")). Much thanks for assistance and solution!!